# Как преобразовать дату в другой формат?

Tags: javascript, jquery

пример

14.02.2022

в

14 Фев. 2022

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так. Дату нужно указать в переменной `fromDate`

```js
const fromDate = '14.02.2022'.split(".")
const date = new Date(fromDate[2], fromDate[1] - 1, fromDate[0])
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ru', {
  month: 'short'
});
const month = formatter.format(date);
console.log(`${date.getDate()} ${month} ${date.getFullYear()}`) // 14 февр. 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

https://qna.habr.com/q/33355

Это должно помочь

new Date().toLocaleString('ru', {
year: 'numeric',
month: 'long',
day: 'numeric'
});

Comment: с сегоднешней датой это будет работать. Но  я получаю именно в формате 24.02.2022